# Compute the derivative of $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ at $x=0$ from the definition

Tags: calculus, limits

> Compute the derivative of $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ at $x=0$ from the definition. You may assume that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}{x^b} = 0,$ where $b>0.$

So I know I need to find the derivative from both sides since the derivative is not defined at $x=0,$ but I'm having trouble evaluating those limits. If someone could help, that would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition, we have that $f'(a)$ is
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.$$

Substituting $a=0$ and $f(0)=0$ gives

$$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{e^{-1/h^2}}{h}.$$

Let $y=1/h^2.$ Then $h\to 0$ iff $y\to \infty$ and $\sqrt{y}=\dfrac{1}{h}.$
Thus the desired limit is equivalent to
$$\lim\limits_{y\to \infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{y}}{e^y}.$$

Let $y=\ln u.$ Then $y\to\infty \Leftrightarrow u\to\infty$ and $e^y = u.$ So we have
$$\lim\limits_{u\to\infty}\dfrac{(\ln u)^{1/2}}{u}=\lim\limits_{u\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{\ln u}{u^2}\right)^{1/2}=0.$$